# Reading a big file in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a big CSV file of 2835 MB having (303354, 3553) row and columns. I am trying to read it using:

```
expanded_codes = pd.read_csv("DxCodeModel.csv", dtype = np.string_)
```

It is taking significant time and finally throws MemoryError . Is there a way to read such big file?

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit system or using 32-bit Python on Windows x64? If so, do not expect it to work. You need a 64-bit Python

Comment: Pass the `chunksize` parameter, see if that helps [example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking)

Comment: @JBernardo: I have 64 bit python on 64 bit machine. Here are the specs: Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Nov  7 2015, 13:21:48) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]